# How can extract data that have specific day from database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, datetime

I have a table contain questions as a data.
Every question has a row named `creation_date`, that store the time of creation of the question as `unix timestamp`.

I want to extract all questions that have  specific day, and I don't care about the month or year.

**For example:**
I want to extract all questions that created on day `16`.

What I done:

```
$today = date('d');

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM questions WHERE qcreation_date = '$today' ");
$numRows = mysql_num_rows($query);
if ($numRows > 0) {
    while ($data = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
        echo $data['questionTitle']."<br/>";
    }
} else {
    echo "There is not any data.";
}
```

`$today` is a variable will contain the day of today, for example, if today is `22/2/2004`, the `$today` variable will contain `22` that represent day of today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DAY()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_day) and [`FROM_UNIXTIME()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime). `FROM_UNIXTIME()` will convert your timestamp into a datetime stamp. `DAY()` will get the day number from it which you can then compare against.

```
SELECT * FROM questions WHERE DAY(FROM_UNIXTIME(creation_date)) = '$today'
```

An alternative way that would reduce your need to use PHP variables in this query would be to use `CURDATE()`:

```
SELECT * FROM questions WHERE DAY(FROM_UNIXTIME(creation_date)) = DAY(CURDATE())
```

FYI, a better way to get today's day is just to use `$today = date('d')`. Using `mktime()` is much more convoluted.